# Updating keras model using tf gradients

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6

I'm trying to build an a3c implementation in keras. I have experience working with keras, but absolutely no experience working with tensorflow. So I would really apreciate if someone could make it as simple as possible, since I want to finish it as fast as possible without diving too deep into tensorflow.

```
    self.session = tf.Session()
    K.set_session(self.session)
    K.manual_variable_initialization(True)
    self.stop_signal = False

    self.model = self._build_model()
    self.graph = self._build_graph(self.model)

    self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    self.default_graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    self.default_graph.finalize()    # avoid modifications

def _build_model(self):

    l_input = Input(batch_shape=(None, NUM_STATE))
    input_layer = Reshape((1, -1))(l_input)

    lstm = LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
    lstm = LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(lstm)
    lstm = LSTM(128, activation='relu')(lstm)

    out_actions = Dense(NUM_ACTIONS, activation='softmax')(lstm)
    out_value = Dense(1, activation='linear')(lstm)

    model = Model(inputs=[l_input], outputs=[out_actions, out_value])
    model._make_predict_function()  # have to initialize before threading

    return model

def _build_graph(self, model):
    s_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, NUM_STATE))
    a_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, NUM_ACTIONS))
    r_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))

    p, v = model(s_t)

    log_prob = tf.log(tf.reduce_sum(p * a_t, axis=1, keepdims=True) + 1e-10)
    advantage = r_t - v

    loss_policy = - log_prob * tf.stop_gradient(advantage)
    loss_value = LOSS_V * tf.square(advantage)
    entropy = LOSS_ENTROPY * tf.reduce_sum(p * tf.log(p + 1e-10), axis=1, keepdims=True)

    loss_total = tf.reduce_mean(loss_policy + loss_value + entropy)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)
    minimize = optimizer.minimize(loss_total)

    return s_t, a_t, r_t, minimize
```

Then it is beeing trained:

```
s_t, a_t, r_t, minimize = self.graph
self.session.run(minimize, feed_dict={s_t: s, a_t: a, r_t: r})
```

Predictions are done this way:

```
with self.default_graph.as_default():
    p, v = self.model.predict(s)
```

So I want to update my keras model weights using these gradients after I finish training in order to save it using model.save('path.h5'). Peudo code:

```
model_weights = model.trainable_weights
model_weights = apply_gradients(grades, model_weights)
model = model.set_weights(model_weights)
model.save('path.h5')
```

The code was taken from here with little changes: https://github.com/jaara/AI-blog/blob/master/CartPole-A3C.py

I found something on this topic but can't really figure out how to actually use it. 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3062
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3069

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem has to do with the algorithm not converging properly. If someone knows what can I do to make it converge? I'm using custom environment and I trained a DQN on this environment in the past and it successfully converged. I aslo implemented target model which I update every 300 steps (or 1 episode in my case).